# Java: Writing Variables to File, and Reading back

Tags: java, variables, try-catch

I am currently using Eclipse Java Neon for my builder, and I am trying to implement a save and load feature into a project i am currently working on. I know it requires me to use a Try/Catch block, but I have no idea how to really handle it. Not only that, but what I tried out is giving me a bit of an error:

```
    try {
        System.out.println("Writing to file...");
        charWrite = new FileWriter("player.dat");
        charWrite.write(player.getName()); //String
        charWrite.write(player.getJob()); //String
        charWrite.write(player.getLevel()); //Int
        charWrite.write(player.getCurrency()); //Int
        charWrite.write(player.getHealth()); //Int
        charWrite.write(player.getExp()); //Int
    }
    catch (IOException excpt) {
    System.out.println("Caught IOException: " + excpt.getMessage());
    }
```

The system seems to recognize what is happening, but when I go to open it and see if it has written, the document is still blank.

And if I am this lost on writing, I am going to be so lost when reading to place it into the Class's parameters.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `.getClass()` is an internal method inherited by `Object`, so every class has it. It always returns an instance of `Class<?>` not String. How did you define your `getClass` method that returns `String` ?

Comment: Now that you've changed your question ... what's your actual error?  Saying your code is "giving me a bit of an error" doesn't really tell us what's wrong.

Comment: Sorry, sorry, sorry. Once again, I do something dumb. It is writing to the file, but it is being written as one long line of characters. I need them to be separate entities to be able to grab them again, and I still have no idea on actually being able to grab them.
Goal: Sam
Commoner
1
50
50
250
Getting on the read: SamCommoner15050250

Comment: When writing to a file, I always use a StringBuilder. I build the string and once the string is complete, I then write that string to a file. It simplifies thing in my opinion.

Comment: Use charwrite.writeln(); if it's available, or put `+ "\n"` at the end of `player.get...() + "\n";` .

Comment: Alright, that seems to be working. Thanks... But what about reading from the file to retrieve the data to get what I need? that part is what is confusing me the most? The goal is to use that data to fill in this:  Player(String setName, String setClass, int currentLevel, int currentCurrency, int currentHealth, int currentNextLevel)

Comment: So what is your actual question?  You don't seem to have asked one yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write an object of type java.lang.Class to a file. If you want the String representation of the class name use toString():

```
charWrite.write(player.getClass().toString());
```

Comment: Upon looking it over, I actually used a wrong call method, making me call something completely different. I fixed it to the call i needed, but now I cannot seem to actually write to the document.

Comment: You need to post your complete code in order for you to get help.

Comment: Um, complete code as in all 1300+ lines of the program? Being able to write to and load from a file is the only trouble i am having with it, and I am absolutely clueless on it.